# Height of views inside ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` inside which I have a `ListView` followed by a few TextViews. The `ListView` that I'm having is filled using a custom adapter and the width of items may vary based on what page we are on. Here's my `ScrollView`:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/options_listview">
        </ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/options_listview">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:text="Explanation:"
                android:id="@+id/explanation_header"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/explanation_text"
                android:layout_below="@+id/explanation_header"
                android:text="stuff..."/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Height of the ListView is not shown completely. I'm programmatically setting the height as:

```
public static void setListViewHeight(ListView list) {

    int height = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
        View childView = list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, list);
        childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        height+= childView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    //dividers height
    height += list.getDividerHeight() * list.getCount();


    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = list.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height;
    list.setLayoutParams(params);

    Log.i("Height ", height + "");
}
```

Now I see in the logs that I'm getting the same height for all the listViews regardless of the item heights. How could I make the ListView completely visible in my scrollview?

Comment: change listview height match parent

Comment: is listview scrolling ? mean have enough object that listview can scroll or cover the entire space ?

Comment: no, the listview isn't scrolling. `ListView` + `TextView` is put inside a `ScrollView` and collectively, it's scrolling, not individually.

Comment: yes thats the issue. two scroll views is not scrolling together. ListView  also have scrollview property i.e scrolling. why you are using scrollview ?

Comment: I have a listview and few textViews below them. All of them couldn't be contained in the screen. So, I was putting all of them in a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Khizar Hayat pointed out, `ListView` shouldn't be used inside a ScrollView` because listview already has a scrolling feature. Doing it that way would have design-conflicts.

So, making 3 different layouts solved my problem:

1. Keeping `ListView` in the first layout file.
2. Making another layout, `header.xml` and put everything above the `ListView` into that layout.
3. Making third layout, `footer.xml` and keeping everything below the `ListView` in that footer layout.
4. Inflating these header and footer layouts in the activity class and adding header and footer to the `ListView`

That way, everything scrolls in one go and all the layouts are shown without any cut. The good thing is we can have any number of headers and footers to the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please try this layout:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tVL"
            android:id="@+id/options_listview">
        </ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tVL"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:text="Explanation:"
                android:id="@+id/explanation_header"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/explanation_text"
                android:layout_below="@+id/explanation_header"
                android:text="stuff..."/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but could we use `orientation` in a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: oh no that line was written mistakenly. sorry about that. if you remove that line code will run smoothly as well.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. The listView is not showing complete. It's scrollable but it doens't show up completely. I'm trying to make the screen such that the listview is completely shown and the TextViews below it follow. So that when I scroll, I start from the first item of listView and stop at the last text of the textview. This is just fixing the textviews at the bottom and bigger listviews get eaten up above.

Comment: ok but you are trying impossible scrolling techniques. i have provided best solution.
Make things simple and generic. this code will run smoothly on every screen size.
Any way best of luck for your code.

Comment: The solution is good, but it simply doesn't answer the question that's asked. The problem is is very straight. How can I show a big `ListView` followed by a textview on an android screen?

Comment: Listview have multiple items and designed to show multiple items which can be more than the screen height.

Comment: That's right. So, if the `ListView` crosses the screen-height, how could I show the views that are below the `ListView`?

Comment: see my code i did same that we have to align list view above of those views.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104831/discussion-between-user5038993-and-khizar-hayat).